# Why systemd doesn't try to stop (some) processes on session termination?

Tags: linux, systemd, session

When I try to close a `logind` session (by logging out), some processes remain running under the session, preventing it from properly terminating, resulting in `user@uid.service` not terminating either. I've heard that the latter is an intended behavior (it is desirable for some units to remain running), but I assume that leaving sessions running is not the proper way to achieve that. Furthermore, when I manually terminate the session, the `user@uid.service` also terminates, so it almost seems like lingering sessions *are* used for this purpose.

To illustrate what I'm on about, this is a part of the output of `systemd-cgls` while I am normally logged in (i.e. Right now):

```
Control group /:
-.slice
└─user.slice
  └─user-1000.slice
    ├─user@1000.service
    │ └─ //various units listed; removed for brevity
    └─session-c8.scope
      ├─4883 login -- sammko     
      ├─4905 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
      └─ //various other processes listed; removed for brevity
```

The output is completely expected. After logging out of the session:

```
Control group /:
-.slice
└─user.slice
  └─user-1000.slice
    ├─user@1000.service
    │ └─ //various units listed; removed for brevity
    └─session-c8.scope
      └─4905 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

`gnome-keyring-daemon` somehow survives, keeping the session alive. If we now run `loginctl show-session c8`, we find `State=closing` in the output. If we proceed to `kill -HUP 4905` we find that the process and the session terminate, taking the entire `user-uid.slice` with it. If we were to proceed with `kill -TERM 4905`, the process would also have terminated. This makes me think that `gnome-keyring-daemon` does not ignore the signals, or anything like that. In case the process needed a signal twice to actually close, I tried to `kill -HUP 4905` before logging out and the process terminated as well.

I was under the impression that systemd attempts to terminate processes with `SIGHUP`, to which `gnome-keyring-daemon` normally responds accordingly. (I have had `gpg-agent` linger along with it as well, and that successfully ignores `SIGHUP`. But that's a different story.)

So my question is: **Why does `gnome-keyring-daemon` keep running after logging out for no apparent reason and how to resolve it, other than enabling `KillUserProcesses`.**

Also, please note that this question is not related to the changes in `systemd-230`

Comment: Very nice question yet an other messy thing with systemd... this also happen if you run a script that call sleep or loop sleep (it get stuck and does not terminate)

Comment: Is there an answer for this? I'm having similar problems with non-terminating sessions on a multi-user computer.